# not fetch full file name after space in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    sb2.Append("<a href=" + "Doc/" + reader[1].ToString() + " 
    target=_blank style=text-decoration:none; color:#000;>" + reader[0].ToString() + "</a><img src=images/new1.gif> </img><hr />");
}
/* for example 
i want to save image name abhi shek.jpg but these hyperlink only get abhi after space not
get anything pls solve these problem */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the attribute is cut at the space is that you don't have quotation marks around the value. What comes after the space becomes a different attribute. You should have quotation marks around the other attribute values also. If you don't have them around the style value, the color won't be part of the style.

Also, spaces in an URL is invalid, you need to encode the name.

```
sb2.Append("<a href=\"" + "Doc/" + Server.UrlEncode(reader[1].ToString()) + "\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"text-decoration:none; color:#000;\">" + reader[0].ToString() + "</a><img src=\"images/new1.gif\"> </img><hr />");
```

Comment: abhi+++shek.jpg image is retrived and resoures could not be found error comes

Comment: @ShivNarwariya: That is the correct way to encode the file name "abhi___shek.jpg" (where _ represents spaces). Is that not the name of the file?

Comment: i cant understand please modify my code with respective encode

Comment: my file name is abhi shek.jpg and they only get abhi after space did get anything and ur code it fill +++ in space and error comes as before resources not found

Comment: @ShivNarwariya: Hm? That's what I did.

Comment: i got the answer guffa my kid not use decode in place of encode

Comment: sb.Append("<img src=news.gif> </img><a href="+"Doc/"+rdr[1].ToString()+" target=_blank onclick=counterfunction("+rdr[2]+")>"+rdr[0].ToString()+"</a>");
                
guffa sir please encode these code as u before